# IAT hooked but hooked function is not being called

Tags: c++, c, windows, api, hook

I am writing code to carryout a hook of the IAT in Windows. I am able to alter the target function's address in the IAT (Kernel32!GetCurrentProcessId), however later in the program when the hooked function is called Kernel32!GetCurrentProcessId is called instead of the hook.

In debugging the process I am able to see the original IAT address for Kernel!GetCurrentProcessId:

GetCurrentProcessId address: 7C8099C0

The function I want to swap in is:

MyGetCurrentProcessId address: 100118BB

I hook the address of thunkIAT->u1.Function and change it from 7C8099C0 to 100118BB, however as I mentioned previously when GetCurrentProcessId() is called from within the program the Kernel32 function is called (not the one I injected).

A portion of the code to carryout the hook is:

```
if(strcmp(apiName,(char*)(*nameData).Name)==0)
{
DBG_PRINT2("[processImportDescriptor]: found match for %s\n", apiName);

VirtualProtect(
    &thunkIAT->u1.Function, // start addres of the zone to "unlock"
    0x010,   // size to protect
    PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, // new permission
    &dwOldProtect           // old permission
 );

procPtr = MyGetCurrentProcessId;
thunkIAT->u1.Function = (DWORD)procPtr;

DBG_PRINT2("MyGetCurrentProcessId() address: %08X\n", MyGetCurrentProcessId);
DBG_PRINT2("procPtr address: %08X\n", procPtr);
DBG_PRINT2("thunkIAT->u1.Function address: %08X\n", thunkIAT->u1.Function);

VirtualProtect(
    &thunkIAT->u1.Function, // start addres of the zone to "relock"
    0x0010,          // size to protect
    dwOldProtect,       // new permission
    &dwOldProtect2      // old permission
);

}
```

Any thoughts? Thank you.

Comment: For one it is possible that the function that gets called is retrieved by means of `GetProcAddress` even though the binary imports it. But the question itself is too broad, with the little information you give.

Comment: Are you injecting a DLL by any chance? If so, you might want to note that every module inside the executable has its own IAT. This means that you may have just hooked the IAT of your DLL module but not the main executable's one. You can iterate through the modules with `Create32Toolhelp32Snapshot`/`Module32First`/`Next` and hook them all.

Comment: I appreciate your input, thank you. To elaborate a little more I am injecting a DLL using the CreateRemoteThread to inject the dll into mspaint.exe.  The code in the DLL is able to iterate through the IATs (about a dozen, including Kernel32 IAT) within mspaint. Within the DLL I call GetCurrentProcessId() directly within "case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:" (after hook is implemented). Stepping through the program with Windbg it appears the call to GetCurrentProcessId() does not invoke a lookup in the IAT (suggesting the value may be cached from an earlier call?). Still plugg'n away. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Making use of the [CreateToolhelp32Snapshot](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682489%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API I was able to hook all the IATs' function calls (did not insert hooks within the injected DLL IATs as this resulted in crashing) to `GetCurrentProcessId()` within my `Helloworld` program which was written to simply report its process id every few seconds. Following injection of the DLL and hooking of `GetCurrentProcessId()` `Helloworld` began calling the hooked function as expected. During my research I did discover some information as to why IAT hooking may not work in certain instances due to built in defenses in modern programs:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12516/Win32-API-hooking-Another-reason-why-it-might-not
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21414/Powerful-x86-x64-Mini-Hook-Engine

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the exe has a self executing code packed. If this is the case, try to inject it after being launched, or after that function has been called.

Comment: Hopefully the OP has it sorted out by now, or has moved on. This question is from 2012 :) -- In any case, this does not answer the question and should be a comment instead.